# matlab double precision confusion

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, precision

Matlab sets inputs to double precision by default, so if I input `a=1/3` then the variable will be converted with double precision

```
>> a=1/3
    a =0.3333

>> whos('a')
    a         1x1                 8  double
```

However, when I input `vpa(a,100)` afterwards, I get:

```
ans=0.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
```

My question is that

since `a` is at double precision and has only 8 Bytes to store its data, why can it have a precision of 100 digits when it comes to `vpa(a,100)`?  In a word, how does Matlab enhance the precision of `a` from 'double' to 100 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the `doc` page of `vpa`, here is the [link.](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html#zmw57dd0e139072)

> **vpa Restores Precision of Common Double-Precision Inputs**
>
> Unlike exact symbolic values, double-precision values inherently
>   contain round-off errors. When you call vpa on a double-precision
>   input, vpa cannot restore the lost precision, even though it returns
>   more digits than the double-precision value. However, vpa can
>   recognize and restore the precision of expressions of the form p/q,
>   pπ/q, (p/q)1/2, 2q, and 10q, where p and q are modest-sized integers.
>
> First, demonstrate that vpa cannot restore precision for a
>   double-precision input. Call vpa on a double-precision result and the
>   same symbolic result.

So the answer is, that Matlab is smart enough to recover your expression, as it is of the form `p/q`.

Comment: Thanks first, it's really helpful!  So Matlab knows the original form of a variable even this variable is stored with double-precision and displayed in decimal fraction ?

Comment: @lixxee It doesn't _know_ that; it just _guesses_ from the double-precision form (which is all it knows). For example, if the input to `vpa` is exactly `3.141592653589793` it guesses you meant the actual value of pi (with its infinitely many decimals)